# Changing a Json Array in D3 for Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, data-visualization

If I have an array in D3.js.

```
data =
[
   {"english":"200","non_english":"100","area":"North"} 
   {"english":"200","non_english":"102","area":"South"} 
   {"english":"200","non_english":"103","area":"East"} 
]
```

How do I concatenate or combine the array to look like this below.

```
 data =
    [
       {"englishBoth":"200,100", "area":"North"} 
       {"englishBoth":"200,102" , "area":"South"} 
       {"englishBOth":"200,103","area":"East"} 
    ]
```

Where the values of english and nonenglish are put together  but with every second value is equal to non english.

So if I used

```
.attr("y", function(d,i) { return y(data[1].englishBoth); })
```

as the y attribute for a D3 bar chart it would return two values and two bar segments could be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop

```
for (i=0;i< data.length;i++) {
    //as string 
    data[i].englishBoth = data[i].english + ", " + data[i].non_english;

    //or as array 
    data[i].englishBoth = [data[i].english, data[i].non_english];

    delete(data[i].non_english);
    delete(data[i].english);
}
```

Comment: instead of a string or an Array is possible for englishBoth to be two integers that d3 can read in?